# Why does is my import requests not being read?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I just made this following another tutorial and want to make one myself, but the import of requests can't not be read or is deemed as 'ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'requests'.

Wherever the * is that is private information.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import smtplib

URL = 'https://www.amazon.com/Samsung-Unlocked-Fingerprint-Recognition-Long-Lasting/dp/B082XXR64G/ref=redir_mobile_desktop?ie=UTF8&aaxitk=08Egp5KhvC3f6cEe802xMg&hsa_cr_id=5004960420401&ref_=sbx_be_s_sparkle_mcd_asin_0&th=1'

headers = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36' }

def check_price():

    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    title = soup.find(id="productTitle").get_text()
    price = soup.find(id="priceblock_ourprice").get_text()
    converted_price = float(price[0:5])

    if(converted_price < 750 ):
        send_mail()

    print(converted_price)
    print(title.strip())

    if(converted_price < 750):
        send_mail()



def send_mail():
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.elo()
    server.starttls()
    server.elo()

    server.login('******' , '*******')

    subject = 'Price fell down!'
    body = 'Check the link: https://www.amazon.com/Samsung-Unlocked-Fingerprint-Recognition-Long-Lasting/dp/B082XXR64G/ref=redir_mobile_desktop?ie=UTF8&aaxitk=08Egp5KhvC3f6cEe802xMg&hsa_cr_id=5004960420401&ref_=sbx_be_s_sparkle_mcd_asin_0&th=1'

    msg = f"Subject: {subject}\n\n{body}"

    server.sendmail(
    '*****',
    '*******',
    msg
    )
    print('The Email has been sent!')

    server.quit()

check_price()
```

Comment: did you installed the "requests" module?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you haven't dowloaded the module.
If you're using pycharm *Preferences > Projects > Python Interpreter* > Find the Requests module and add that.

Or you can just pip install the module from your terminal which is

```
pip install requests
```

(but if you're using different ide you need to look where you can add modules)
that way you downloaded the module for calling in the script that you wrote.

I think that should do the work.